# Ruby on Rails form to update model adding/substracting the input value to the current value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to add a form to update a model adding the input values to the current values but printing only the input values. 
Say we have :cars = 50 and user inputs 30. I want to print 30 and the car value after the submit should be 80.

```
= form_for @shop do |f|
  - if @shop.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@shop.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this shop from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @shop.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message

  .field
    = f.label :cars
    = f.text_field :cars
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Add cars'
```

I know the question is not very specific but i can't find a place to start. I tried looking around but I cant seem to find the proper search keywords combination.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual attribute on your model. Let's say `cars_increment`

```
attr_reader :cars_increment

def cars_increment=(value)
  @cars_increment = value
  self.cars += value
end
```

Now setting that value will increase by `cars` by that value, but you're still displaying cars_increment, so the user will see what they entered.

Just make sure to use `cars_increment` and not `cars` directly in the view

Do be aware, that this will run into issues if your code sets the value of cars_increment more than once per request or when traffic on your website increases and multiple requests are trying to change this value simultaneously.